# Do webAudio Panner and/or SteroPanner nodes introduce a suitable delay between left and right channels?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Shouldn't panning not only alter volume, but also left-right delay according to the distances from the source to the ears? The documentation doesn't seem to mention this, but differential arrival time of sound is a central part of human aural localization. If these panner nodes don't do it, do DelayNodes have sufficient time resolution to be used, and can they be connected appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

The `StereoPannerNode` does not have different delays.  The `PannerNode` with type "equal-power" doesn't either, but the "HRTF" type would since the impulse responses through the head would take in to account the location of the source relative to each ear.

A 'DelayNode` probably has sufficient resolution to delay the signals if that's what you want to do.

I've never had problems with localization when using the HRTF panner. I've always been able to tell if the source is above or below, or in front or behind, or left or right.